# how to get element by tags +5th value using selector

Tags: html, css-selectors, jsoup

```
    <table>
                    <tbody>
I WANT it =>            <input type="hidden" name="prodCd_8801043014830" id="prodCd_8801043014830" value="8801043014830">
                        <input type="hidden" name="itemCd_8801043014830" id="itemCd_8801043014830" value="001">
                        <input type="hidden" name="categoryId_8801043014830" id="categoryId_8801043014830" value="C001001700010001">
                        <input type="hidden" name="maxQty_8801043014830" id="maxQty_8801043014830" value="20">
                        <input type="hidden" name="minQty_8801043014830" id="minQty_8801043014830" value="1">
                        <tr>
                         <-- CONTENTS-->
                        </tr>

I WANT it       =>      <input type="hidden" name="prodCd_8801043015738" id="prodCd_8801043015738" value="8801043015738">
                        <input type="hidden" name="itemCd_8801043015738" id="itemCd_8801043015738" value="001">
                        <input type="hidden" name="categoryId_8801043015738" id="categoryId_8801043015738" value="C001001700010004">
                        <input type="hidden" name="maxQty_8801043015738" id="maxQty_8801043015738" value="31">
                        <input type="hidden" name="minQty_8801043015738" id="minQty_8801043015738" value="1">
                        <tr>
                        <-- CONTENTS-->
                        </tr>
```

HI I want get elements in first and 1+5n input hidden tags values . there are between hidden tag groups TR tag   and input hidden tags not has container.

i tried 2ways but they returns wrong values except only first value

```
Document doc=Jsoup.connect("URL").timeout(5000).get();
a is integer value 

for(int a=0;a<10;a++){

int n = 0+5a 

1.Elements testattrval = 
 doc.select("table tbody input[type=hidden]:eq("+n+")");

2.Elements testattrval = doc.select("table tbody input[type=hidden]:nth-child(+"n+")");

}
```

Comment: That HTML is invalid. You cannot put input elements where you have them.

Comment: why dont you use a className or an ID ?

Comment: That HTML is invalid??  0_0 i want to learn  HTMLparsing  so I tried parsing information from internet shopping mall  .  :(...  in this page , #productform (fomtag) has this table.  I appriciate your advice thak you!  i'm more tring :)   http://www.lottemart.com/search/search.do?searchField=&searchTerm=%EA%B0%90%EC%9E%90&viewType=list

Comment: jsoup is not jQuery, and Java is not JavaScript. Please don't get these things mixed up.

Comment: Also if the original markup is really that malformed, then you're in for a really hard time I'm afraid. @Pawan Kumar Sharma: You are not supposed to fix invalid markup in questions.

Comment: you're right thank you for advice  BoltClock :)  I will careful don't that things mixed up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For iterating through a collection of object in jquery, you can use the .each() method. If you specifically want every 5th value, check if the index of the item is divisible by 5.

```
$("input[type='hidden']").each(function (index){
    if(index % 5 === 0){
      console.log($(this).val());
    }
});
```

Here I am logging the value of the input element to the console window.

Comment: He originally tagged jQuery but someone updated his tags after I posted this. I'm still confused why it is the accepted answer though as it looks like he does want to use jsoup.

Answer (score 1):

U can simply do it with **[jQuery](https://api.jquery.com/)** like this-

```
$("input[type='hidden']:nth-child(5)");
```

To select 5th element.
More can be found **[here](https://api.jquery.com/nth-child-selector/)**.